# Let $P \left( A \right) > 0$ and $ P \left( B | A \right) = P \left( B | C \right) $ where $ C $ is A complement.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $P \left( A \right) > 0$ and $ P \left( B | A \right) = P \left( B | C \right) $ where $ C $ is complement of set $A$. Are $A$ and $B $ independent sets?

I think not but I can not find example that shows so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the are! We have $${P(B\cap A)\over P(A)}= {P(B\cap A')\over P(A')}$$

Since $P(A')= 1-P(A)$ and $$P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A')= P(B)$$ we have

$$P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A){1-P(A)\over P(A)} = P(B)$$ From here we get $$P(B\cap A) = P(B)\cdot P(A)$$

Comment: That is exactly how I solved this, but my professor said opposite, so I wanted to check.

Comment: It could go wrong only if $P(A)=1$

Comment: agreed. Thanks :)